# Angular 4 : How to use custom validator with data from back-end

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In a form, the button submit becomes enable only when the form is valid. A particular input contains datalist with data from back-end. I want to return the form invalid if data filled by the user is not in the datalist. So, i need a custom validator which check if user data is equal to data from back end.
Data from back-end is a list of objects *listOfArticles* which contains reference numbers and other data.

So, I try to create a function for custom validator in the same component file, but it doesn't work for 2 reasons :

- I don't know how to retrieve the path of my *listOfArticles* "*refer.refNumber.input*"
- I get error in my console : "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

**Function for custom validator :**

```
export function ValidateRefNumber(control: AbstractControl) {
  for (let refer of ArbologistiqueComponent.listOfArticles) {
     if (control.value == refer.refNumber.input) {
        return true;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

My entire **component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { ManagementArbologistiqueService } from "../management-arbologistique.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-arbologistique',
  templateUrl: './arbologistique.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arbologistique.component.css']
})

export class ArbologistiqueComponent implements OnInit {

  private reponseTest: String;
  private listOfArticles :Array<Object>
  private pathDownload: any;
  private myFormGroup: FormGroup;
  fileToUpload: File = null;
  private buttonSubmitEnabled: boolean = false;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private managementArbo: ManagementArbologistiqueService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      itemRows: this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
    })

    this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.buttonSubmitEnabled = false);
    this.getListBdd();
      }


  initItemRows() {
    return this.fb.group({
      ... //other fields
      refNb: ['',[Validators.required, ValidateRefNumber]],
      ... //other fields

    })
  }

  addRow(index: number) {
    console.log("functionAddRow called");
    const control = <FormArray>this.myFormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
    control.insert(index, this.initItemRows());

  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    console.log("functionDeleteRow called");
    const control = <FormArray>this.myFormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

  sendForm() {
    this.buttonSubmitEnabled=true;
    console.log("functionExportCalled");
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "exportation";
      this.managementArbo.postProducts(subroute, JSON.stringify(this.myFormGroup.value))
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.reponseTest = res; console.log('reponse:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));

    });
  }

  getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.listOfArticles = res; console.log('reponse:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
  }

  get refNb() {
    return this.myFormGroup.get('itemRows.refNb');
} 
}

export function ValidateRefNumber(control: AbstractControl) {
      for (let refer of ArbologistiqueComponent.listOfArticles) {
         if (control.value == refer.refNumber.input) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
```

input with datalist (**component.html**) :

```
<input list="refNumbers" formControlName="refNb" type="text" name="article" maxlength="8" size="15" required title="8 characters" />

<datalist id="refNumbers">
     <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles">{{ref.refNumber.input}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will provide you an answer with a simple example, then you can transform it as you need.

 Lets say we have this list of articles:

```
  articles = [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "test 123"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "test 345"
    }
  ];
```

And we want to check if the user type in the input text one of the id's of the articles, otherwise, the form is invalid.

We have this little piece of HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
    {{article | json}}
</div>
<form [formGroup]="cForm" (submit)="submitForm(cForm.value)" novalidate>
    <input formControlName="article" type="text" name="article" required />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="!cForm.valid">
</form>
```

So I just print the array for debug, and we have input which has formControlName of article. and we have a button which is disable if the form is invalid.

Init the formGroup:

```
this.cForm = this._fb.group({
  article: [
    null,
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValues(this.articles)])
  ]
});
```

So we have a formGroup with simple validation of required, and our new validator named matchValues.

```
export const matchValues = (valuesToCheck: any[]): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    const controlValue = control.value;

    let res = valuesToCheck.findIndex(el => el.id === +controlValue);
    console.log(res);
    return res !== -1 ? null : { matched: true };
  };
};
```

I simply wrap it in a function which received the array of articles, and I'm trying to find an article id which is matching the value of the input text. If I dont find any, I'm returning an object:

```
{ matched: true }
```

which is the error of the control, so you can access this error with 'matched' same as you access required or minlength or any other error.

I hope its clear enough and gives you a nice kick off to solve your a bit more complicated problem.

**--UPDATE--**
To make it more clear: 

findIndex searching in the array for the first item that match the condition and return the index of the item or -1 if nothing found, in this case, I've check if the value of the input from the user match any ID from the list. so as long as my res is not equal to -1, thats mean that I found an item that match so the validation pass, but if res === -1 there is an error, so I send new object with the error name matched so you can handle it later. anyway in this case, I didn't find any item that matched the id, so its an error.

**--UPDATE2--** 
You got some trouble, So I've included a working example.
[Check this out](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yxn26o1m7)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but i still have an error "Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined" as if my list was empty, but she's not? because i initialize my list before the form...I checked it in my template with the ngFor attribute. I don't understand...

Comment: Yet, in the console, i see the error before the message of the request to initialize my list...So it looks like my list is initialized after call the function and i don't understand why

Comment: @Josept, try to call all your initialization, in ngOnInit(), and follow this example, it is working, so try to see whats failing in your side. good luck !

Comment: I have no more errors displayed in my console because i think I forgot to declare my list with : `public listOfArticles: Array<Object> = [];`. But I use your function validator to compare values and it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why we use _findIndex_ in your exampe, we want to compare values and not index ?

Comment: @Josept, Its validator not a class function, You said you want to check if the user fill the input with data from the list, otherwise its invalid, so I check if there is ID in the list like the user type, and if I dont find any, its invalid.

Comment: Yes but i don't understand why we assign index to the var res and not value ID ? To be clear, I don't really understand the syntax of your validator...

Comment: findIndex searching in the array for the first item that match the condition and return the index of the item or -1 if nothing found, in this case, I've check if the value of the input from the user match any ID from the list. so as long as my res is not equal to -1, thats mean that I found an item that match so the validation pass, but if res === -1 there is an error, so I send new object with the error name matched so you can handle it later. anyway in this case, I didn't find any item that matched the id, so its an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "I send new object with the error name matched **so you can handle it later"** ? In my case, -1 is always displayed even when I choose an item from the list, I'm desperate...

Comment: @Josept, I've included the live example, check it out and good luck!

Comment: I looked at your example, and I just added a level to the list, and it doesn't work anymore... That's exactly my case, could you take a look at it? For the rest I'll manage, don't worry : [https://codesandbox.io/s/vnjjy27myy ]

Comment: @Josept, It is working, you just have to remove the '+' from the controlValue in the validator, since in my case I had to parse it to number, in your case, you are using a string.